# Routing is not working in laravel5 when call made from ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm calling the jquery function on click event in signin page. From there I'm calling the $ajax function. This $ajax function should call the controller and process the function and return back with response. I have connected it using the routes.php. While running the application I'm getting error that "Requested page not found 404 error". I think there is some problem with routing. Somebody help me out to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

The routes.php is as follows

```
Route::post('signin', 'LoginController@signin');
```

Jquery function on click event is in login_register.js file

```
$("#form-login").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var log_password = "";
    var log_name = $("#log_username").val();
    var password = $("#log_password").val();

    if(password.trim() !== "")
    {
        log_password = md5(password);
    }
    $(".loginmessage").html('');
    $(".login").attr("disabled",true);
    $("#spin_signin").addClass('show');
    var req =  new Request();
    req.data =
    {
        "email":log_name,
        "userpassword":log_password

    };

    req.url = "signin";
    RequestHandler(req,processlogin);

});
```

The ajax call made is in jquery.ajax.js file. I have given type as POST and datatype as JSON

```
function RequestHandler(request,response,resdata){
    $=jQuery.noConflict();
    var domain = "http://localhost/laravel_login/public/";
    var tempurl = domain+request.url;
    if(request.isfulluri){
    tempurl = request.url;
    }

$.ajax({

    type: request.type,
    url: tempurl,
    data: request.data,
    datatype:request.datatype,
    success: function(data){
        if(resdata != null && resdata != '')
        response(data,resdata);
        else
        response(data);
    },
    error: function(err){
        if(err.responseText == null || err.responseText == ""){
            alert("Error: Check your internet connection");
        }
        else{
            alert("Error:"+err.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

My controller class(LoginController.php) contains

```
public function signin(){
    $response = array();
    $useremail = $this->input->post('email');
    $userpassword = $this->input->post('userpassword');
    if($useremail == '' || $userpassword == ''){
        $response['iserror'] = TRUE;
        $response['message'] = 'Please fill all the fields';
        echo json_encode($response);
        return;
    }
    else{

        $result = $this->UserAuthenticate->loginUser($useremail,$userpassword);

        echo json_encode($result);
        return;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have a route defined for your full path:

`laravel_login/public/signin`

You can use `php artisan route:list --path=signin` to see if your route is registered.

Also, in your controller method, instead of

```
echo json_encode($result);
return;
```

i would use

```
return response()->json($result);
```

as this will automatically set the proper HTTP headers for you. This way, the variable passed to your javascript callback function will be a Javascript object, without requiring additional parsing.